# Se ejecuta el proceso pero no se cumple la condicion " sequence(rle(MiBase$Cedula)$lengths) "

Tags: r, validación

Estoy realizando una validación por clientes, debo garantizar que el cliente no este repetido, por lo cual he utilizado la siguiente línea:

```
MiBase$Conteo <- sequence(rle(MiBase$Cedula)$lengths)
```

Con lo cual me daba una columna con el conteo por cédula, 1 si sólo estaba una vez el cliente en esa base o mayor a dos (>2) si aparecía más veces.

Mi problema es que se ejecuta el código pero me coloca 1 en toda la columna y no los 2 o más conteos que tenga la cédula.

Answer (score 1):

El algoritmo [`rle()`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) trabaja por bloques contiguos, de forma tal que si tu vector de cedulas, no estuviera ordenado, esta función no detectaría repeticiones. Por ejemplo:

```
x <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B')
rle(x)$lengths
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

Vemos que `B` es un valor repetido, sin embargo no lo detecta como tal, por que no es un valor contiguo, en cambio:

```
x <- c('A', 'B', 'B', 'C')
rle(x)$lengths 
[1] 1 2 1
```

Y ahora sí, al estar ordenado el vector, detecta correctamente que a partir del segundo ítem hay un "bloque" de valores repetidos de longitud 2. Si quieres seguir usando esta forma de detectar y numerar ocurrencias, deberás "ordenar" previamente el `data.frame`:

```
MiBase <- MiBase[order(MiBase$Cedula), ]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ordené la información y funciono. Muchas gracias :)